# Opening an excel file with partial name

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to open an excel file without knowing the full path name?

For example:
`TEST_03222018.csv` is the file name located in `C:\test\folder`

the known part of the string\path is

```
C:\test\folder\TEST_03
```

is there a way to open this csv sheet without the rest of the path (preferably without using `InStr()` or any `If, While` loops

Comment: How would you know you are opening the correct file by using a partial file name, for instance if you have 2 or more files with C:\test\folder\TEST_03 in the file name?

Comment: because only the files with specific name at the beginning are the CSV files

Comment: FWIW that *really* sound like the kind of assumption that's safe & true, until it isn't anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Function findFile(strFileStart as string) as string

findFile= Dir(strFileStart & "*", vbNormal)

End Function
```

Echo, @Ryan Wilson's comments about having more than one file with the same prefix though.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dir with a wildcard to confirm the existence and if found, open it.

```
dim fp as string, fn as string

fp = "C:\test\folder\"
fn = "test_03"

fn = dir(fp & fn & "*.csv")

if cbool(len(fn)) then
    workbooks.open fp & fn, delimiter:=","
end if
```